# how to save changes from DataSet to physical Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I've been looking at this problem for a while and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I want to save changes from DataSet(**ds.Tables("Login")**) to physical Database (**Data Source='|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.accdb**). But it doesn't work correctly. Data not saved in physical Database.

Any Ideas how to solve it ??

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtUsername.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(New DataTable("Login"))
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.accdb'"
    Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Login"
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds.Tables("Login"))

    dt = ds.Tables("Login")

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Username") = txtUserName.Text
    dr("Password") = txtPassword.Text

    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    ds.AcceptChanges()
    dataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables("Login"))
End Sub
```

Comment: First, are you looking at the correct database? |DataDirectory| resolves to a BIN\DEBUG folder when running inside the IDE (or APP_DATA for ASP.NET). Second, did you get an error message or not when you call update?

Comment: And REMOVE the AcceptChanges before calling UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article and particularly step 7 which states you will need to set the UpdateCommand.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301248